# Function overriding to add text and numeric character in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm very new to TypeScript. I have found a problem where i have two types of user input controls `TextInput` and `Numeric`. In Numeric, it takes only digits and in textinput it takes all texts.

Now my objective is: if it takes TextInput add various characters returns correct values like: `"1","a","0"` it would return `"1a0"`. if it takes NumericInput add various characters returns correct values like: `"1","0"` it would return `"10"`. Also for Numeric Input it can be `"1","a","0"` and it would return `"10"`.

Now here's my approach till now:

```
class TextInput {
    public value : any ;
    constructor(n: any) {
        this.value = n;
      }
    public add(c: any) {
        c + `${this.value}`;
    }

    public getValue() {
        return this.value ;
    }
}

 class NumericInput extends TextInput {
    public valueNum ;
    constructor(a: any) {
        super(a);
        this.valueNum = a;
    }
    add(a: any){
        if (typeof a == "number"){
            a + `${this.valueNum}`;
        }else {
            a + `${this.value}`; 
        }
        
    }

 }

 function userInput() {
    const input = new NumericInput();

    input.add("1");
    input.add("a");
    input.add("0");

    console.log(input.getValue());
}
```

I actually don't know where i'm going wrong with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't understand what your are trying to do. input.add(a) should failed as the constructor is expecting a number, not a string...

Comment: This: `input.add("1");` should be a compiler error, because of `add(a:number)`.

Comment: Actually what i want is if i do this: const input = new NumericInput(); the output should be "10" which means it would ignore the "a" and if i do this const input = new TextInput(); then the output should be "1a0" . Hope you guys understood my problem now @Jerome

Comment: I have updated my NumericInput class to make it better understandable. Please see if this makes sense now @KrisztiánBalla

Comment: Why does "add" return a value instead of modifying "value" or "valueNum"?

Comment: Removed the return from the code. But i don't think thats the problem now. I think i need to pass some argument to new NumericInput(). Because it's showing that "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0". Do i need to pass anything there? Also i have updated the code. Please check @KrisztiánBalla

Comment: There are some things I would change in your code: 1. Don't use "any", like never. "any" disables type checking for the variable which destroys the point of using TypeScript. 2. I don't see a reason why NumericInput should be a sub class of TextInput. 3. You removed the "return" in the "add" method, but the method still does not change the "value" property of the object, so the method basically does nothing. 4. Your constructor error could be solved by making the parameter optional or by providing a default value.

Comment: Would you mind changing the code what you are suggesting. I'm very new to typescript and that's why i'm just assuming and coding things. @KrisztiánBalla

Comment: From my point of view what you're trying to achieve can be done by having a variable in which you concatenate your characters and a RegEx that "erases" all the numbers when you call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my suggested solution:

```
class TextInput {
    private value: string;

    public constructor(v: string = "") {
        this.value = v;
    }
    
    public add(v: string): void {
        this.value += v;
    }

    public getValue(): string {
        return this.value;
    }
}

 class NumericInput extends TextInput {
    public override add(v: string): void {
        const num = parseInt(v, 10);
        if (isNaN(num)) {
            return;
        }

        super.add(v);
    }
 }

 function userInput() {
    const input = new NumericInput();

    input.add("1");
    input.add("a");
    input.add("0");

    console.log(input.getValue());
}
```

Explanation:

- `NumericInput` is derived from `TextInput` and overrides the `add` method. (note: The `override` keyword is new in TypeScript 4.3. If you are using an older version simply remove that keyword.)
- The `add` method of `NumericInput` checks if the value to add is a number. If it isn't then the method does nothing. Otherwise it calls the base class's add method which concatenates the value to the `value` property of the object.
- You should try to keep properties (eg: `value`) private and use public methods to alter the state of an object.
- The input seems to be a string, so I don't see a point in using `any`. Moreover never use `any`, because that disables type-checking of the variable in TypeScript. If you really don't know the type then use `unknown`.